# how to run go-unit-tests pre-commit hook to run with option -p

Tags: unit-testing, go, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I was looking into this golang-precommit hooks repository: https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang

`go-unit-tests` hook runs the command `go test -tags=unit -timeout 30s -short -v` but what if I want go hook to run command with
`-p=1` option. Is there any way to achieve this?

Here's the content from my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/dnephin/pre-commit-golang
    rev: v0.4.0
    hooks:
      - id: go-fmt
      - id: go-unit-tests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there isn't given that hook directly, but that repo isn't really adding too terribly much, you could replicate what you want via a `repo: local` hook (untested):

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: go-unit-tests
        name: go unit tests
        entry: go test -p=1 ./...
        pass_filenames: false
        types: [go]
        language: system
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Answer (score 0):

/blatant self-promotion

I invite you to have a look at my golang pre-commit hooks project:

- [github: TekWizely/pre-commit-golang](https://github.com/TekWizely/pre-commit-golang)

The project includes built-in hooks for "go test":

- [README -> go-test](https://github.com/TekWizely/pre-commit-golang#go-test)

These hooks were specifically designed to enable you to pass extra arguments to the go tools.

Just use pre-commit's built-in args mechanism:

- https://pre-commit.com/#passing-arguments-to-hooks

Additionally, each hook has a version to run against different scopes:

- Individually Modified .go Files
- All .go Files in Repository
- Full Module Containing Modified .go|go.mod Files
- All Modules In Repository
- Full Package Containing Modified .go Files (deprecated)
- All Packages in Repository (deprecated)

note: Available scopes are dependent on what each tool actually supports.

Finally, there's a mechanism to invoke general go tools that do not
(yet) have built-in hooks (its hard to keep up with them all).

Per your original question, here's an example of running go test with `-p=1`:

```
    -   repo: https://github.com/tekwizely/pre-commit-golang
        rev: master
        hooks:
        -   id: go-test-mod
            args: ['-p=1']
```

I hope you'll give my project a try.  I think you'll find it offers the best available pre-commit hooks for golang.

(feel free to ask any clarifying questions, but please don't ask for too much support here - the issue and discussion trackers on the project page are a better place for such things)

[edit: grammar]